# Spring Integration Xmpp 4 - Send create muc request

Tags: spring, xmpp, spring-integration, smack, multiuserchat

I configured spring integration with xmpp and I can send message to other jid.
To build the message I use the following method:

```
Message<?> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("Test Message").
        setHeader(XmppHeaders.TO, "pino@chiarottos-macbook-pro.local").
        build();
messageChannel.send(message);
```

Now I would like to create a chat room, I tried to figured how to build a message containing a multi user chat request without success.

Any help?

using:  `XmppHeaders.TYPE` set to `"groupchat"` and `XmppHeaders.TO` to "myroommmm" does not work.. The xmpp server log:

```
[info] <0.609.0>@ejabberd_c2s:open_session:1105 ({socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.16208>,<0.608.0>}) Opened session for chiarotto@chiarottos-macbook-pro.local/resource 2016-04-12 15:55:40.987 [info] <0.609.0>@ejabberd_s2s:new_connection:406 New s2s connection started <0.611.0> 

[info] <0.611.0>@ejabberd_s2s_out:log_s2s_out:1253 Trying to open s2s connection: chiarottos-macbook-pro.local -> myroommmmme with TLS=false 2016-04-12 15:55:40.999 [info] <0.611.0>@ejabberd_s2s_out:open_socket:246 s2s connection: chiarottos-macbook-pro.local -> myroommmmme (remote server not found)
```

I'm running an integration test

Upadate 2:
Using:

```
MultiUserChat multiUserChat = new MultiUserChat(xmppConnection,"prova");
        try {
            multiUserChat.join("soisdjdsoijds");
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I get the folling error:

```
remote-server-not-found
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketCollector.nextResultOrThrow(PacketCollector.java:196)
    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.enter(MultiUserChat.java:352)
    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.join(MultiUserChat.java:516)
    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat.join(MultiUserChat.java:451)
    at radiosa.service.muc.MUCService.testRoom(MUCService.java:83)
```

(The server is correctly configured and It is working)

Answer (score 1):

The `ChatMessageSendingMessageHandler` is designed only for sending messages.

All the multi-user chat management (creat, join, leave etc.) must be done via `org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChatManager`.

Although you still can send message there using `ChatMessageSendingMessageHandler`:

- The `XmppHeaders.TO` header must be a `room` name according to the JavaDocs:

  ```
  * @param jid the name of the room in the form "roomName@service", where "service" is the hostname at which the
  *        multi-user chat service is running. Make sure to provide a valid JID.
  */
  public synchronized MultiUserChat getMultiUserChat(String jid) {
  ```
- And the `XmppHeaders.TYPE` header must be as a value of `Message.Type.groupchat`

Comment: thanks, if I use MultiUserChatManager I have to pass it my XMPPConnection bean?  By the way I'm using the latest version of spring-integration-xmpp (4.2.5) and It depends on a smack version that doesn't contains MultiUserChatManager.

Comment: Yeah... I see. Looks like it has been introduced since `Smack 4.1.x`. We support that since SI-4.3. I guess you can do the same via just `MultiUserChat`: `public MultiUserChat(XMPPConnection connection,  String room)`.

Comment: But Using MultiUserChat I would not use channel anymore,just xmppconnection, right?  I would like to use channel and just send minimal info to my xmpp server in order to create the room.

Comment: I think you have to `join` milti-user chat first of all, before sending the message. And I said you already: via `ChatMessageSendingMessageHandler` you only can send `Message` Packet to the `xmppconnection`. You have to use `MultiUserChat`  directly for any group-chat management. Although you can wrap all the operation into the `service-activator` and send command messages to manage the chat.

Comment: See you logs: `remote server not found`. That is not Spring Integration problem. Sorry.

Comment: thanks, my local server works, if I send a message to another jid using the same integration test  everythings works. The error is showed with the muc creation attempt. I'm not saying that spring does not work. I'm asking help to achieve my goal.

Comment: Yeah... I'm not familiar with `MultiUserChat`. I added a `Smack` tag to your question with hope that someone from the Ignite Realtime will take a look.

Comment: "Although you can wrap all the operation into the service-activator and send command messages to manage the chat" there is an example on internet? For me it's like arab :-)

Comment: M-m-m. No, of course, no. That is out of Spring Integration scope. And even more: such a logic doesn't feet the EIP purpose. So, I'd recommend just use `MultiUserChat` chat directly for management.